# 1/2 от чего-то или чего-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее написать: "Одна вторая чего-то" или "Одна вторая от чего-то"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Современная норма требует использования при управлении словами "часть", "половина", "треть", "доля" и т.п. беспредложного родительного падежа. Ранее в этих (и некоторых других, весьма далеких от темы) случаях использовался родительный с "предлогом от".

*"Другие случаи"  это, например, "генерал от инфантерии" - при современном "маршал авиации".*

Comment: Пять - это одна вторая десяти. Так правильно?

Comment: Грамматически - да.

Comment: Думаю, что грамматика должна не управлять семантикой, а наилучшим образом выражать ее. Предлог ОТ  не нужен там, где он семантически излишен, но его желательно использовать в тех случаях, когда он проясняет смысл выражения.  Например: «Эта сумма равна примерно одной второй  (от) общей задолженности по платежам». Предлог ОТ совершенно СВОБОДНО используется в математике, что видно из конкретных примеров: «Чтобы найти дробь (часть) от числа, нужно это число умножить на данную дробь».  «Найдите: 1/2 от числа 40, 1/3 от числа 150, 1/4 от числа 100».

Answer (score 2):

1. Думаю, что возможны оба варианта.
2. Вот, например,  предложение: 15 человек – это три пятых от общего состава кабинета министров. Здесь предлог  ОТ после  дроби вполне на месте. Поэтому делаем вывод, что выбор варианта зависит от ситуации.
3. В общем виде это выглядит примерно так. 
   Когда мы НАЗЫВАЕМ дробную часть предмета в каком-то сообщении, то предлог ОТ не нужен, например:  (1)Леса занимают 1/2 территории страны.
   Но если  содержанием сообщения является СООТВЕТСТВИЕ между дробью  и целым числом, то предлог нужен, например:  (2)Леса занимают всю центральную часть страны, это 1/2 от ее общей  территории.
4. Также в математике, например:
   (1)Обозначим стороны треугольника как «а»  и «1/2а» – предлог ОТ не нужен.
   (2)  Число «пять» составляет ½ от числа десять – предлог ОТ нужен.

Comment: Интересная версия.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, первый вариант верен, так как фраза полностью звучит так: "Одна вторая часть (чего?)...

Answer (score 1):

Это БЕСПРЕДЛОЖНОЕ управление по Розенталю: 
§ 1825. К беспредложному сильному управлению существительных относятся все случаи такого управления род. падежом, при котором возникают отношения необходимого информативного восполнения  Это следующие случаи.
  1) В роли главенствующего слова выступает сущ. с количественным значением: пуд соли, часть добычи, четверть урожая, доля секунды,четверка быков, дюжина ложек, тысяча дел, миллион рублей, масса вопросов, половина каравая, большинство людей, меньшинство собравшихся, килограмм хлеба,  пара сапог.

Одна вторая часть чего? так же, как часть чего?

http://mariab.h1.ru/index.files/RuLang/synt/pss_noun5.html